# Typescript: best way to handle dependencys between service calls onInit

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi im looking for typescript best practices dealing with dependencies between service calls onInit. 
I have 4 functions that is run onInit the first 3 is populating 3 child components ( filtering droopdowns). 
These then return a array with the selected filter values. 
When i have the selected filter values i wanna run the last function which use the values from the previous 3 to build a query which then send a request for data. 
This data is then used to populate a table.
Currently the fourth function is called at the end of the third function.
I feel like there has to be a better way to deal with async calls so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
    this.getCatalogueStatuses();
    this.getCountries();
    this.getAgreementTypes()
    // dependent on function above for filtering
    this.getClaimTypeAndPrices();
```

Comment: am I wrong or belongs asking for best practices to this stack site [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you share what you've tried and what problems you're having. As it stands now, this is a "best practice" question which are off topic for this site, because there is no correct answer. With that said, take a look at reactive programming. https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: also: https://blog.nrwl.io/reactive-programming-in-angular-7dcded697e6c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might want a `forkJoin`? (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin):

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

...

forkJoin(
    this.getCatalogueStatuses(),
    this.getCountries(),
    this.getAgreementTypes(),
)
.subscribe(([catalogueStatuses, countries, agreementTypes]) => {
    // use return data for method below
    this.getClaimTypeAndPrices();
});
```

This assumes your methods `this.getCatalogueStatuses(), this.getCountries() and this.getAgreementTypes()` return `Observables`.